# Request is redirected to no layout page

Tags: presentation

I noticed that in my logs there are a ton of entries like this:

> 5920 09:09:26 WARN  Request is redirected to no layout page. Item: sitecore://web/{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}?lang=en&ver=1 Device: {FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3} (/sitecore/layout/Devices/Default)

I am not seeing any odd visual behavior.   Is there a way to further debug what issue is placing this into the logs.

I'm using Sitecore 8.1

Comment: Have you published the site, or are you running in `Live Mode`?

Comment: @jammykam Published

Comment: Are you seeing this on a CD or CMS instance?

Answer (score 5):

Try clearing this setting:

`<setting name="RedirectURLPrefixes" value="/sitecore" />`

If it makes a difference it's a reasonable assumption you got some less than ideal URLs going on in your solution. Like http://site.domain/sitecore/content/home/news - that type of thing.

Comment: After clearing the value, the errors still are recorded.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen in two cases -

1. On CD server if there is no sitecore folder, and someone requested http://domain/sitecore (This will go to check /sitecore/ item, not folder)
2. [http://domain/?sc_itemid={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}](http://domain/?sc_itemid=%7B11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111%7D)

To know, from such URLs are requested, only easier option is track this is by checking IIS logs at the time of such errors

Comment: 1.) /sitecore folder definitely exists, if I unsecure the folder I can login to it, but the errors keeps going into the log.

Comment: I don't follow how IIS logs help in this scenario, isn't the request being made http://domain/?sc_itemid={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111} ? If so, won't the IIS logs just show the same thing ?

Comment: In case of any custom development if "/sitecore" item is mapped as a context item by mistake or in case of selected as a content item in aliases, etc. it won't have domain/?sc_itemid={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111} URL, but still referring that item. We can find such URLs from IIS Logs.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably one of your customizations is incorrectly generating urls to, or directly requesting the content node, which has no presentation.

One approach could be to add [real-time logging](http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2015/08/25/improve-your-sitecore-log-with-realtime-output-and-calling-class/) to the solution and then try to find what generates the requests by accessing the site, backend and front, to visually see any correlation. You could then determine if the request is coming from the browser by checking the network panel, if it's not there, presume it's being requested by the server somehow. Scheduled tasks can do strange things out of normal context.

Perhaps there is a query or expression somewhere that is failing to find the expected node and ends up pointing to the top level item.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned previously, it's quite likely that you have bad URLs stored in your index, perhaps due to custom URL logic.

1. Navigate to your local install of Solr and look at the schema of your index(example: `https://localhost:8983/solr/YOUR_INDEX_NAME/schema`)
2. Using the field dropdown, search for a field that might store a URL (try searching for "url")
3. Once you have the field name, navigate to https://localhost:8983/solr/#/YOUR_INDEX_NAME/query
4. Try the following query: `your_url_field:*/sitecore*`
5. If results are returned, inspect the values. It's likely that there are problematic values in there.

Comment: Ha, someone responded to a question from over six years ago???